# How to navigate to new browser window using partial title text using either Python, or JavaScript or Robot Framework and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

During my tests, we need to click on links that open webpages in new tab. In some cases, we see the test fail due to inclusion of multiple space or tab characters in the title text. One of the examples of such titles are -

```
"Looking for more information about US?${SPACE}${SPACE}Find out more from ... Get your questions answered."
```

I am trying to switch to the window using the partial text "Looking for more information about US" instead of using the whole title text. But so far could not find a way to do that.

My current codes are as follows:

```
Test for "Frequently Asked Question"" Link at the bottom panel
    Hide Promo Carousel
    execute javascript  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
    Click External Link and Return      partial link:Frequently Asked Questions     Looking for more information about us?  Find out more from ...... Get your questions answered.
```

and the keyword is :

```
Click External Link and Return
    [Arguments]     ${Element}  ${ExtUrl}
    ${CurrTitle}=   get title
    click element   ${Element}
    sleep   5s
    run keyword and continue on failure  select window  ${ExtUrl}
    sleep   1s
    run keyword and continue on failure  select window   ${CurrTitle}
```

Is there a way to locate and navigate to the window using partial text from the title? Kindly suggest if there is any way in robot framework, Python or JavaScript to achieve this.

Comment: You can use regular expression with groups and then compare the keyword with the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below example the custom keyword will use the current browser and then using a pattern search for the tab and select it. If there are more or less than 1 result, it will fail.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Select Window Using Partial Title
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com    chrome

    Click Element    link:About    CTRL
    Sleep    5s
    Title Should Be    Google


    Switch Window Using Title Pattern    Over*
    Title Should Be    Over - Google

    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***


Switch Window Using Title Pattern
    [Arguments]    ${title_pattern}
    ${current_title}    Get Title            # Save the current  tab title
    ${window_titles}    Get Window Titles    # Cycles through the tabs.
    Switch Window       ${current_title}     # Restores the original tab focus

    ${match_count}      Get Match Count    ${window_titles}    ${title_pattern}

    Run Keyword If    '${match_count}'=='0'    Fail    No Browser Tabs found that meet the "${title_pattern}" pattern.
    Run Keyword If    '${match_count}'>'1'    Fail    Too many Browser Tabs found that meet the "${title_pattern}" pattern.

    ${matches}    Get Matches        ${window_titles}    ${title_pattern}   
    Switch Window    ${matches}[0]
```